# How do I describe my "academic profile" for graduate school application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, canada

I am filling [McGill's Area of Research and Applicant Profile Form](https://www.mcgill.ca/ece/files/ece/arap_form.pdf) for admission to the Electrical Engineering M.Eng. program. I'm not sure how I should answer this:

"**Academic Profile:** Describe your academic profile, highlighting particular achievements and relevant scholarships or awards."

My scholarships and awards take up about 0.15 of the space provided, and I can't think of a particular achievement. Can I use this space to describe the projects I completed, the software I learned and particular skills I learned through coursework and special topics that were covered? I don't get to upload a CV for this application, and I was hoping I could mention these in this space. However I'm not sure if it would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Projects completed are more important than skills learned from coursework. Give preference to what distinguishes you from every other student. If you did an internship, mention that. If you worked on a project at a university department, mention that. If you did a Bachelor's Thesis, write about what you did there.

Saying something like "I learned about LTI systems in course X and I acquired MATLAB programming skills in course Y" will not distinguish you from every other Electrical Engineering student, so those statements should have the last priority.

Comment: The thing is I don't know if that's the right place to put those. For example I included my thesis and internship in the first field and TAships in the last one.